# How to show shopping cart/stock only when you are logged in?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

Is there a way to show the shopping cart and the amount in stock when you login to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check if the user is logged in any controller or phtml, you need to add

```
<?php 
    if( ! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        //not logged in
    }else{
        // logged in
    }
?>
```

Comment: great! And where do I have to add this code?

Comment: tried it in view.phtml but that's not the one

Comment: it will work, what error its showing now

Comment: no error at all, I placed it at the top of view.phtml but it was still showing when i was logged out. I cached everything before refreshing

Comment: can you send the entire code which u using

Comment: i have updated the answer try like that

Comment: I do get an error now with that code. But is the view.phtml the right one? I see also another view.phtml. Which is the one that I'm supposed to use?

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: open footer.phtml file and place this code..first check whether this code running or not

Comment: But in your new code, the access is denied, that is not the case. Only the link to the shoppingcart you have to see when you are logged in, same for the indicator for what is in stock. The rest of the page should be visible to everyone else. Only when you are logged in you can see the stock and cart. 

Which code you would like to see? From what file?

Comment: the access denied is just a text you can place your else condition content

Comment: oke, i'm searching for foother.phtml now

Comment: added the code to the footer.phtml, but also not working. placed it at the top but still showing when logged of.

Comment: when you login it must be showing welcome and when logout then access denied, correct ?

Comment: The code you gave first, worked for the price. That is showing for customers when they are logged in. The same needs to be done for delivery/in stock and for the shopping cart.

Tried to add the code to in stock part, and it did worked, only also the description disappeared

Comment: Yesss! I got it worked! Thank you for you input and patients! I had to put the specific div in the else {}

Comment: great ...happy coding :)

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to do that